# can it be solved without vieta formulae ??

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

recently i came across an anonymously remarkable algebra question which is as follows If the polynomial $$F(x)= 4x^4 - ax^3 + bx^2 - cx + 5$$ where $a,b,c$ belongs to $\mathbb R$ has 4 positive real zeroes(roots) say $M,N,P,L$ such that $$M/2 + N/4 + P/5 + L/8 = 1$$ then find the value of $a$, by using AM-GM inequality & the Vieta formulas i got $a=19$; what i am curious is if this could be solved without using vieta formulas i tried a lot but with no fruits, So can anyone tell ?

Comment: How could you avoid using the fact that $F(x)=4(x-M)(x-N)(x-P)(x-L)$?

Comment: hmmm a really nice idea.....why it did not strike me earlier...!!!!..nevertheless..i shall give it a try

Comment: Actually that was not meant as an idea but as an argument that using Vieta is unavoidable :)

Comment: How can $a$ be unique? I am expecting that the first polynomial has four positive real roots for any choice of $(a,b,c)$ in a open set $U\subset \mathbb{R}^3$, while the condition on the linear combination of the roots is a closed condition, so I am expecting that both the constraints hold in a closed subset of $U$ and there are many possible $a$ that work.

Comment: well i only got only one value for it

Comment: true even that way vieta formulas comes back.....nothing new